# unity localized language wont stay when restarting the app

Tags: unity-game-engine, localization

I'm currently implementing a multi-language system for my game, using the build in localization from unity. I got it so far that I can change the language via buttons and that the language of the text changes.

My current problem is that it won't save the selected language when restarting the app. It got around this problem with storing the current language index inside a PlayerPrefs variable, which works but leads to a weird bug.

This changes the language via buttons

```
public void changeLanguage(string language)
    {
        //this will change the current language to the one given via the buttons
        //it will also change the current language in the player prefs
        //and then the language select panel will close
        if (language == "de")
        {
            LocaleSelected(0);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("current_language", 0);
        }
        else if (language == "en")
        {
            LocaleSelected(1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("current_language", 1);
        }

        languagePanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    static void LocaleSelected(int index)
    {
        //this will change the current localized language to the one given with the index
        LocalizationSettings.SelectedLocale = LocalizationSettings.AvailableLocales.Locales[index];
    }
```

This will fire when starting the app

```
IEnumerator loadLocalization()
    {
        yield return LocalizationSettings.InitializationOperation;

        LocalizationSettings.SelectedLocale = LocalizationSettings.AvailableLocales.Locales[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("current_language")];
    }
```

When starting the app inside the first second, the language is first English (maybe because of my selected default language inside the localization menu) then it changes to German (maybe because of the language of my phone) and then it changes to the language stored inside the PlayerPrefs variable.

This is a picture from the localization window
[image]

Is there a way to change maybe the default language via code or to prevent it from using the system language?

Comment: I don’t see you saving your playerprefs

Comment: @BugFinder I mean yeah I could save the playerprefs, but I also store different data using them and it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the value into PlayerPrefs by yourself, as the system does it automatically when `SelectedLocale` is changed.
Source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/saving-selectedlocale-with-playerprefs.1111849/#post-8394945

You need to define "Player Pref Locale Selector". I attached an example of my config.
[image]

**P.S.:** `LocalizationSettings.SelectedLocale.SortOrder` returns current locale's ID.